# Cannot update Outlook 2016 msi installer to support Office.js requirement set 1.4

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

We're developing and Outlook web add-in that needs requirement set 1.4, which is supported by both Outlook 2016 CTR and MSI.

We have Outlook 2016 MSI 64-bit installed on 2 different machines. Machine A has  Outlook installed long ago and it has windows auto update turned on. Machine B has just had Outlook installed today without any update.

When we tested the add-in on both machine, it's loaded into Outlook of A, but not B. We figured out that Outlook on A is the latest version but Outlook on B is not, so we tried to trigger Windows update on B manually, but it cannot find any update for Outlook. We then tried to download and install the latest update for Outlook from this [site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032235/description-of-the-security-update-for-outlook-2016-august-14-2018), but the result is not as expected:

- OUTLOOK.EXE is updated to 16.0.4732.1000, which is the same with
  machine A
- Outlook > File > Office Account > About Outlook still shows:
  16.0.4266.1001, which is different from machine A: 16.0.4639.1000
- Requirement Set is updated to 1.3, not 1.4 (we used F12Chooser to
  check)

Is there any wrong with our update process? How can we have Outlook on B fully updated just like on machine A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recommend getting updates through Microsoft Update since it will update all of the right files.

In your specific case, for Outlook 2016, try also installing [this update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022223/july-3-2018-update-for-office-2016-kb4022223), which is needed for requirement set 1.4.

Comment: Thank you. After installing the latest update and the one you mentioned, we got Outlook running with requirement set  1.4